# Footer text-decoration not working

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to set up the footer, but I'm unable to remove the lines under the text. I also would like to change the color of the text. I tried using `text decoration:none` under `.footer ul`, but that was unsuccessful.

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  color: beige;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-shadow: -2px -2px black;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  position: relative;
}

.head-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.head-link:hover {
  margin: 20px auto 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}

header {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/xD3POCF.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  max-width: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.header-image {
  background-size: cover;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: darkblue;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monospace;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: double;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  padding: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  min-width: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 0;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #04116f;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.sidebar {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -650px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.sidebar ul {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 10%;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/yiMoYpV.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 50px center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 700px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  color: goldenrod;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  align-content: space-between;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<header>
  <h2 style="bottom: -130px">
    <a href="#" class=h ead-link> A  B  E  L</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="dropdown" style="float;right">
    <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="right;0">
      <a href="#">About </a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <title>A B E L </title>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="hl-content" class="content"></div>

  <p>
    <span style="color:navajowhite">
      <b>Hello, Welcome to my website.</b>
    </span>
    <BR></BR>

    My name is Abel, a senior college student currently residing in the Bay Area. This portfolio will give you a good background about me including my specialties, expertise and even hobbies. As you can probably tell from the background pictures, I like traveling
    and taking photos!
  </p>
  <p>This is my first ever website that I created using HTML and CSS, and it's a pleasure to finally be able to share it with you. I am happy to receive any feedback, recommendations or opportunities from you, so don't hesitate to contact me.</p>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="#"> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#" target="#"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see text decoration and color doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag on your question?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow! I've formatted your code, but unfortunately, your code is still **riddled** with syntax errors (such as written output outside of `<body>`). Please read up on the [**basics of HTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics), and ensure that you follow the required HTML structure in order for your code to display output correctly. You can validate that your code is correct with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer > ul > li > a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the links in your footer explicitly.

```
.footer ul a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this css :

```
.footer ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. I wanted this only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my best, this might help as per your requirement(underline and color):

add this in your code,

```css
.footer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: tan;
  padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .footer ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

appreciate if it is useful enough.